# Looping through arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx-8

Hi I'm am working on creating a sortOf a bank application using javafx8. I seem to be having a trouble with regards to adding new account. What I'm trying to do is to create a loop to read the list if the same account number exist and prompt the user that it already exist. Can you please check what I'm doing wrong.

```
BTW I have corrected out all the typo's Eclipse always asks me to correct those before compiling
```

This is the list in my main app

`private ObservableList<Person> personData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

Here is what i did to access the list on another class

```
public ObservableList<Person> getPersonData() {
        return personData;
    }
```

And here in my PersonEditDialogController class to access the list it did this

```
MainApp mainapp = new MainApp();
    ObservableList<Person> personData = mainapp.getPersonData();
```

and here is my code to verify user input

```
private boolean isInputValid() {
        String errorMessage = "";

        if (accountNumField.getText() == null || accountNumField.getText().length() == 0) {
            errorMessage += "Not a valid account number!\n"; 
        }
        //TO LOOP THROUGH THE LIST
        Person person = null;
        for (Person a : personData) {
            if ((accountNumField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(a.getaccountNum()))){
                person = a;
                break;
            }
        }
        // CODE THAT DOES NOT WORK
        if (accountNumField.getText().equals(person)){
                    errorMessage += "Account number already exist\n";
        }

        if (errorMessage.length() == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // Show the error message.
            Dialogs.create()
            .title("Invalid Fields")
            .masthead("Please correct invalid fields")
            .message(errorMessage)
            .showError();
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: We are going to need more info than this, for example, what is accountNumField? And we might need to know a bit more about Person too while you are at it...

Comment: accountNumField is an assignment to a textfield where the user can input the desired account number

Comment: ok, and what about Person? I ask because you have the line accountNumField.getText().equals(person), does this mean Person extends String or something?? How would the equals() method even be usable in this situation?

Comment: Person is just a class with instance variables. From what i understand after the loop has found the account number it assigns itself to person. the .equals check and tells the user that the account numne already exist

Comment: Right, but in order to use .equals, it needs to be comparing itself to a string, something person is not. When you run it, what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you have unbalanced curly braces (there's an extra closing curly brace **}** after the line `person = a;`) And so the function seems to end after the loop.

Comment: I tried removing it and it does not work. from what i understand is its gonna loop through the list and if  it finds it, it assign it to person

Comment: @Onedaynerd Well what does it return? Or rather, what does the program do? Does it even compile?

Comment: My program compiles it just that line of code that doenst work. I don't know where the error is. If its in the way that i tried accessing the list from another class or the loop itself is not workin

Comment: Well, the braces are definitely unbalanced. That's why (or one of the reasons why) the code isn't working. What does it say the error is when you remove the brace?

Comment: @Onedaynerd Yes, you keep talking about error, is the error bad output or what?

Answer (score 0):

I **think** you need this just to get all your curly braces balanced

If what you have shown in your question is not your actual code, please post the real code and what your error messages are.  What you posted has too many syntax errors for anyone to help you with your logic.

```
private boolean isInputValid() {
    String errorMessage = "";

    if (accountNumField.getText() == null || accountNumField.getText().length() == 0) {
        errorMessage += "Not a valid account number!\n"; 
    }
    //TO LOOP THROUGH THE LIST
    Person person = null;
    for (Person a : personData) {
        if ((accountNumField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(a.getaccountNum()))) {
            person = a;
            // }  -- nPn COMMENETED OUT LINE 
            // break;   -- nPn COMMENETED OUT LINE 
        }
    }
    // CODE THAT DOES NOT WORK
    if (accountNumField.getText().equals(person)){
                errorMessage += "Account number already exist\n";
    }  // -- nPn ADDED CURLY BRACE


    if (errorMessage.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // Show the error message.
        Dialogs.create()
        .title("Invalid Fields")
        .masthead("Please correct invalid fields")
        .message(errorMessage)
        .showError();
        return false;
    }
}  // --nPn ADDED CURLY BRACE
```

Comment: The curly braces were just typo's eclipse always asks me to correct them before compiling the program